# Binding textblock text to multiple datagrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to display in a textblock all the hostnames from selected rows in a datagrid.

The datagrid ItemsSource is an observable collection of systems pulled from an XML file.

I can successfully bind the hostNameList.Text to a single selected item in the datagrid with binding, but I don't know how to how to display when multiple rows are selected.  The datagrid can vary in how many systems it lists so I can't predict and just have a certain number of textblocks.

I've come close in getting this achieved but the issue is I have to change selections in the datagrid for the hostNameList.Text to update.  I know that is what the selectionChanged Event does but other events like MouseLeftButtonDown, etc behave in a similar fashion.  I'd like it to update immediately like when it is bound to a single row selectedItem.

Any ideas?

Below is the code I have where all works except it will not update until the selection changes in the datagrid.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ClientDataGrid"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource lightGreenBrush}"
      AlternationCount="2"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      SelectionChanged="ClientDataGrid_SelectionChanged" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly="False"
                            Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" >
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox x:Name="checkSelectAll"
                      Checked="checkSelectAll_Checked"
                      Unchecked="checkSelectAll_Unchecked" />
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource statusImageConverter }}"
                           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Status}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hostname"
                        Binding="{Binding Hostname}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP"
                        Binding="{Binding IP}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subnet Mask"
                        Binding="{Binding SubnetMask}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gateway"
                        Binding="{Binding Gateway}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code behind:

```
private ClientDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add all names to a list
    List<string> clientsSelected = new List<string>();

    foreach (Clients c in ClientDataGrid.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            clientsSelected.Add(c.Hostname);
        }
    }

    //Build string of hostnames that are changing and set to textbox text
    hostNameList.Text = string.Join(", ", clientsSelected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event handler for the MouseUp event on the DataGrid rows:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <EventSetter Event="MouseUp" Handler="DataGrid_MouseUp" />
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Code behind (using DataGrid's SelectedItems property):

```
private DataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Add all names to a list
    List<string> clientsSelected = new List<string>();

    foreach (Clients c in ClientDataGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
        clientsSelected.Add(c.Hostname);
    }

    //Build string of hostnames that are changing and set to textbox text
    hostNameList.Text = string.Join(", ", clientsSelected);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Patrick.  Your suggestion does result in an event being trigger right away which is great but for some reason the textbox text does not update still until I click in a different row in the datagrid.  Very odd because it does go through and updates the textbox text in the code behind. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I figured out something that worked for me.  I ended up using a DataGridTemplateColumn. Thanks again for those who responded with suggestions.  Much appreciated!  Note when I tried using the SelectedItems property it always just listed the last checkbox selected so I changed back to itemssource and that worked.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ClientDataGrid"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource lightGreenBrush}"
      AlternationCount="2"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      SelectionChanged="ClientDataGrid_SelectionChanged" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Checked="CheckBox_Checked" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource statusImageConverter }}"
                           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Status}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hostname"
                        Binding="{Binding Hostname}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP"
                        Binding="{Binding IP}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subnet Mask"
                        Binding="{Binding SubnetMask}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gateway"
                        Binding="{Binding Gateway}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add all names to a list
        List<string> clientsSelected = new List<string>();

        foreach (PrairieDeskClients client in prairieDeskClientDataGridConfigurationStep1.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (client.IsChecked == true)
            {
                clientsSelected.Add(client.Hostname);
            }
        }

        //Build string of hostnames that are changing
        applyChangesToTheseClients.Text = string.Join(", ", clientsSelected);
    }
```